# Firebase Permission denied for setValue: or removeValue:

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have started working with `firebase` for `ios`.

I am following this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/109706/firebase-tutorial-getting-started.

I have created my project in firebase. Added ref URL in iOS project but i can’t even add an item.

It is giving this response

> [Firebase] setValue: or removeValue: at /grocery-items/test failed:
>   permission_denied.

can anyone help me with this

Comment: It could be helpful if you add the actual code you are using to set the `reference` and to set `snapshot`.

Comment: The database for projects created in the new Firebase Console are only readable/writeable by authenticated users. See this question for a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403954/the-read-failed-permission-denied-error-in-firebase/37404053#37404053

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial was very helpful for me. But, notice it is referring the the previous version of `Firebase`. So, unless you change few lines of code, the Grocer app would not work correctly. Your best route is to finish the app and then follow the [migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/) for the new `Firebase`.