# Check if an object with a certain query exists in Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to check if an object with a certain property set to a value exists.

Here's a sample of what my data on Firebase might look like:

```
object: {
  object-one: {
    id: "something"
  }
}
```

And now I want to fetch an object with an id that doesn't exist:

```
let objectsRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("object")
let query = objectsRef.queryOrderedByChild("id").queryEqualToValue("something else")

query.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
  // Never get's called
})
```

As there is no entry with `id = "something else"` the completion will never get called. But how should I know if it's not called because of internet problems or just because that object really doesn't exist?!?

Comment: Do you always know the object-one key? are trying to get multiple items that match that value?or only one?

Comment: Basically I'd like to know weather there is at least one item with a specific ID. The ID would be the UID of the logged in user

Comment: I just did q quick test, the `.Value` event fires for me on on a non-existing node. In that case `snapshot.exists()` is false. Are you sure you have permission to read? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403954/the-read-failed-permission-denied-error-in-firebase/37404053#37404053

Comment: For me the event also fires on non-existing nodes with the same query you are using.  you could use the observeSingleEventOfType version with "withCancelBlock" to find out if you have permission issues ..reference here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_database_query.html#method-detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use valueEventListner. It fetches the current data and listens for any further updates. In case the data is not present dataSnapshot.exists() will return false.

e.g.
My database contains list of user objects, with emailId being one of the fields in each user object.

```
[
    user1: {emailId: abc@xyz.com},
    user2: {emailId: abc1@xyz1.com}
]
```

I can search by emailId field and check if that user is present or not.

```
ref.orderByChild("emailId").equalTo("unavailable@xyz.com").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                System.out.println(dataSnapshot.exists());//false, if values is not present
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

[If no data exists at the location, the snapshot's value will be NSNull](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-start)

Comment: The OP was asking *why* the event was't being called at all, not what's returned when it is.